# How to convert an .exe to it's source files and back(only back doesnt work)

Tags: windows, zip, exe

I downloaded a game that is a pure .exe nothing else and I want to edit some game graphics to skin it myself when I convert the .exe with WinRAR to a zip or a folder I get the desired files but I can't convert it back to an .exe. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

So I found a way to solve this I don't know why it works but it does.
Step 1: Right-click the .exe and unpack with WinRAR to a folder
Step 2: Edit the files you want for example change some sprites
Step 3: Put the original exe in the folder you unpacked and start it.

now for some reason the changes work.